# Database directory issue

Tags: ios, sqlite

Our app has been rejected with this indications by Apple:

"Please verify that only the content that the user creates using your app, e.g., documents, new files, edits, etc. is backed up by iCloud as required by the iOS Data Storage Guidelines. Also, check that any temporary files used by your app are only stored in the /tmp directory; please remember to remove or delete the files stored in this location when it is determined they are no longer needed.

Data that can be recreated but must persist for proper functioning of your app - or because users expect it to be available for offline use - should be marked with the "do not back up" attribute. For NSURL objects, add the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute to prevent the corresponding file from being backed up. For CFURLRef objects, use the corresponding kCRUFLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute."

We are surprised because our database is in the Library root folder (not in Caches), and no content is stored in the Documents folder. So, why they quote iCloud and Data Storage GuideLines related to Documents folder?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That your app's database is in the library folder has nothing to do with iCloud backup. Presumably, you have enabled iCloud. Because you have only one database, everything will be backed up.

Instead, if your database contains seed data or downloadable data that is not user specific, you should separate it from the user data. Create a second database and enable one for iCloud, the other one not.

That being said, there is the opinion that sqlite and iCloud do not mix very well, due to frequently corrupted database files. Considering your report, that seems to be true.

It would be preferable to use **Core Data** instead. I have done many migrations of sqlite to Core Data, say, from Android apps. After you get your Core Data to play nicely with the other databases (online, other mobile platforms) you will find that you can write elegant and concise code that performs extremely well.

Apple will give you the opportunity to post a short message explaining what you changed when you resubmit.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, we don't have enabled iCloud, and the database is all about app information data, not user related. I think Apple is not being fair with this issue.

Comment: Maybe you have inadvertently enabled iCloud? Anyway, that's what Apple's message says. In this case, just disable iCloud. If you are confused, contact apple via the response form, they usually respond very quickly and are quite friendly.